# How is 1000 Raka'as of Nawafil prayed in Shahri Ramadan according to Shiism?

Tags: salat, fiqh, ramadan, shiism

Bismillah. Alhamdulillahi rabbil-'alamin. Was-Salatu was-Salam 'ala Ashraful Anbiya Sayyidina Muhammad wa 'ala 'Alihi Muhammad.

---

It is highly recommended to pray 1000 raka'as during Shahri Ramadan according to the Imams of Ahlul Bayt.

**Question is, How are these 1000 Raka'as of Nawafil prayed in Shahri Ramadan? How are they distributed across Shahri Ramadan?**

According to [this internet page](https://www.islamic-laws.com/taraweeh.htm) Shaikh Toosi(r.a.) wrote:

> In addition to the recommended prayers of other months, perform a
> 1,000 units prayer in the blessed month of Ramazan. The breakup of
> this is – 20 units in the first twenty nights, eight units between
> Maghrib and Eshaa and the rest 12 units after Eshaa prayers. Perform
> 30 units in the last ten nights and perform 100 units each in all
> three nights of Qadr.

So I made following table

[image]

Comment: And where is the question here?

Comment: `How are these 1000 Raka'as of Nawafil prayed in Shahri Ramadan? How are they distributed across Shahri Ramadan?` Text in bold.